# Run Windows backup with a different account

Tags: windows, backup, nas

I am using Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 and have *File History* and *Windows Backup* enabled to store backups to a shared NAS folder regularly.

Since I am concerned about ransomware trojans, I want to make sure, that an infected system cannot affect my backup files.

My plan is

1. restrict access to the shared NAS folder to a special backup account
2. configure the backup software to use this account (without exposing the credentials)

Is this possible?

EDIT: [this question](https://superuser.com/q/457853/12349) discusses other/better ways to achieve security, but does not address running backup software with restricted accounts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A virusproof (ransomware...) strategy for backup on a NAS?](http://superuser.com/questions/457853/a-virusproof-ransomware-strategy-for-backup-on-a-nas)

Comment: The only way to protect yourself from ransomware encrypting your backups is for those backups not to be connected to your pc or network at the time of the infection.

Comment: @CharlieRB yes, that is very helpful, thanks. I still keep my question open, since I am particularly interested in the account configuration

Comment: @Ramhound why would you say that a connected, but inaccessible drive would be insecure?